# Store addresses as hash

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hash, geolocation

I have about 1 millions addresses and there will be more. For every address I need to know location (latitude, longitude).

Some addresses might be duplicated. For example, two records: "USA, New York, Times Square" and "USA New York Times Square". I normalize these addresses to "usa new york times square" and store them in table "cached_addresses" so later when I need to know latitude/longitude for address I can query this table.

The main question is: can I store md5/sha1/sha256 hash instead to gain some performance boost/storage optimization?

The query in question is: `SELECT lat, lng FROM cached_addresses WHERE address = ?`, parameter `?` equals to `usa new york times square`. Here address represents normalized address string.

With hash it will be: `SELECT lat, lng FROM cached_addresses WHERE address = ?`, parameter `?` equals to `hash_function('usa new york times square')`. Here address represents hash of normalized address string.

I use postgresql, but it is also possible to use mysql if it can give some performance/storage optimization.

Comment: It seems that you already know that you can store a hash of the address field and how to query it. Is your question about "can I" or maybe "should I...to optimize the query"?

Comment: Can you? One way to find out: Benchmark it.

Comment: On a side note, it may be useful to keep the parsed addresses as text - and in multiple fields - so that any change to the standardizer can be applied on the address cache. The same is true for address changes (street name change, city amalgamation, postal code change etc)

Answer (score 2):

As far as MySQL is concerned, you can expect performance improvements if you hash the values and store them in an efficient way. I'm pretty sure that this applies to postgress as well since it's a common problem DBAs and developers face.

When you store the full (normalized) address in a column `address` you need *at least* N bytes for each record, where N is the number of characters in the address. It would be 25 for your example. But when character sets come into play, things get complicated and you might need a lot more than N, perhaps 4*N for `utf8`. And then you need to index that (more storage space depending on m*N) and the DB engine will need to perform string comparisons using *collations* etc.

On the other hand, when you hash the address, using SHA-256 for example, you only have to store 32 *bytes* no matter how long the address might be. Further more, you can store the bytes in a `BINARY(32)` column (fixed storage for data and index) and perform *binary comparisons* when querying it.

Examples:

```sql
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN address_hash BINARY(32);
UPDATE t SET address_hash = unhex(sha2(address,256)));
SELECT c1, c2 FROM t WHERE address_hash = ?;
-- ? would be the SHA-256 hash of the address
```

More on that on the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html).

If performance/storage is the most important factor and you application can tolerate some collisions, you can even use `MD5`. This would require half the bytes but you will need to handle possible collisions (two different addresses producing the same hash).